# How to best convert a fully encrypted drive into a Virtual Machine?

Tags: backup, windows-xp, virtualization, encryption, physical-to-virtual

I have a Windows XP laptop that uses *GuardianEdge's Encryption Plus* to fully encrypt the drive from bootup.  What I would like to do is install a much larger (unencrypted) hard drive with Windows 7 on the laptop and turn this fully encrypted drive into a Virtual Machine that can be ran in either Virtualbox or VMWare on the Windows 7 host.

I've read many howto's that talk about using an imaging tool like *Acronis True Image* to image the drive then passing that through *VMWare's VCenter Converter* to turn it into a format that VMWare can understand.  Unfortunately this seems to all far apart when you are dealing with a fully encrypted drive because Acronis cannot recognize the file system and attempts to do a sector-by-sector copy of the entire hard drive.  This is extremely wasteful since the drive is 120GB but the file system is only using 10GB of that.  Even if I were OK with going with an inefficient 120GB sector-by-sector copy, I'm not sure that I could even restore and run this under VMWare or Virtualbox.

Unfortunately, the Guardian Edge boot-time login comes up only after the hard drive has been selected as the boot device; preventing me from being able to decrypt the drive prior to booting an Acronis True Image CD so that it can recognize the underlying file system.

I'm sure I'm not the first person to want to do this but I am having a heck of a time finding solutions to this problem.  All suggested/answers welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could decrypt the drive first using the [GE Recover CD(FTP Link)](ftp://getftp.guardianedge.com/download/access_utility/GEHDRecover9.5.0.iso).  For 10GB of data a decryption shouldn't take too long.  GE would still be installed afterward and you could re-encrypt after using acronis and the converter.  I think you might also be able to use the [access utility](ftp://getftp.guardianedge.com/download/access_utility/GEHDAccessUtility9.5.0.iso) do decrpyt it but I haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 3):

I've not tried this on encrypted drives, but what about some P2V software that runs inside Windows? That way the disk copy should take place on top of GE's decryption.

Give [Disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) a go. If that doesn't take, I've personally had success with using [VMware vCenter Converter](http://www.vmware.com/download/converter/getconverter.html) to image unencrypted drives while XP is running.

Hopefully one of the two should create a usable image.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using imagex from the [WAIK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=696DD665-9F76-4177-A811-39C26D3B3B34&displaylang=en) to create a wim file and redeploy it to my target machine.  You should be able to stick the [access utility](ftp://getftp.guardianedge.com/download/access_utility/GEHDAccessUtility9.5.0.iso) on the waik boot cd and then create the image